# List<T>.SelectMany(), Linq and lambda

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, lambda, extension-methods

I have a class.

```
public class MedicalRequest
{
    private int id
    private IList<MedicalDays> Days 
    private string MedicalUser
    ...
}
```

and another

```
public class MedicalDays
{
    private int id;
    private DateTime? day
    private MedicalRequest request
    ...
}
```

I'm using nhibernate to return a list of all the MedicalDays within a time span. I'd like to do something like this to the resulting list

```
//nhibernate query
IList<MedicalDays> days = daysDao.FindAll(searchCritCollection);

//select a list of days from resulting list
IEnumerable<MedicalDays> queriedList = 
        days.SelectMany(i => i.MedicalRequest.MedicalUser == employee);
```

Linq tells me that the type cannot be inferred by the usage.  I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong, and if there is a preferred way of doing something like this.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Jason's answer is the way to go. Here's a good example of how `SelectMany` is meant to be used: http://weblogs.asp.net/zeeshanhirani/archive/2008/03/26/select-many-operator-part-1.aspx

Comment: Thanks David, as I posted a bit further down, I had tried Where() and got no results because I had some extra whitespace at the end of my employee string.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It seems to me, that you want to filter the list `days`. If that's what you want, you should use

```
days.Where(i => i.MedicalRequest.MedicalUser == employee);
```

Comment: I tried that, and I don't get any error, I also don't get any results. I can see the value of employee and i.medicalrequest.medicaluser being equal, but I get no results in queriedList

Comment: Never mind that last comment.  I had some white space at the end of one of my strings. Thanks for your time and quick answer.